# Python: Is there a way to sort a string using only selected characters in the string?

Tags: python, string, sorting

For example, is there a way to sort the following:

```
model_1_depth/depth_w/read/_79__cf__79
model_2_depth/depth_w/read/_73__cf__73
model_3_depth/depth_w/read/_67__cf__67
model_4_depth/depth_w/read/_61__cf__61
model_5_depth/depth_w/read/_55__cf__55
model_6_depth/depth_w/read/_49__cf__49
model_7_depth/depth_w/read/_43__cf__43
model_8_depth/depth_w/read/_37__cf__37
model_9_depth/depth_w/read/_31__cf__31
model_10_depth/depth_w/read/_25__cf__25
model_11_depth/depth_w/read/_19__cf__19
model_12_depth/depth_w/read/_13__cf__13
model_13_depth/depth_w/read/_7__cf__7
model_13_point/weights/read/_4__cf__4
model_12_point/weights/read/_10__cf__10
model_11_point/weights/read/_16__cf__16
model_10_point/weights/read/_22__cf__22
model_9_point/weights/read/_28__cf__28
model_8_point/weights/read/_34__cf__34
model_7_point/weights/read/_40__cf__40
model_6_point/weights/read/_46__cf__46
model_5_point/weights/read/_52__cf__52
model_4_point/weights/read/_58__cf__58
model_3_point/weights/read/_64__cf__64
model_2_point/weights/read/_70__cf__70
model_1_point/weights/read/_76__cf__76
model_0/weights/read/_82__cf__82
```

using only the integer that comes after "model"? I have tried to capture only these integers using `re.sub("_", "", re.sub(r'[^\w]', '', key[6:8]))` to get the integers to sort, but I'm unable to use the sorted result to locate back the original strings since there will be some duplicates, like '1' belongs to both `model_1_point/weights/read/_76__cf__76` and `model_1_depth/depth_w/read/_79__cf__79` and it won't be possible to distinguish the two.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

EDIT: To clarify, the following strings are in a dictionary, and I'm wanting to sort such that 1 is the smallest and 13 is the largest.

Comment: are these strings in a `list` or something?

Comment: If the problem you're having is that that is not a list, you can make it one by doing `your_string.split()`

Comment: `b = sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(x.split('/')[0].split('_')[1]))` but I would prefer a `re`gex solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a version using regex:

```
rgx = re.compile('model_(?P<number>\d+)')
srtd = sorted(mods, key=lambda x: int(rgx.match(x).group('number')))
```

the regular expression `model_(?P<number>\d+)` captures the numbers `\d+` (greedy) after the string `model_`. in the [`key` of `sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) this is then converted to an `int`.

i assumed your input is in a list called `mods` of the form:

```
mods = [
    'model_1_depth/depth_w/read/_79__cf__79',
    'model_2_depth/depth_w/read/_73__cf__73',
    'model_3_depth/depth_w/read/_67__cf__67',
    'model_4_depth/depth_w/read/_61__cf__61',
    ...
    ]
```

if it is just the string you presented you'd have somehow bring it into this form.

---

a little less verbose (no named group) the very same could be achieved like this:

```
rgx = re.compile('model_(\d+)')
srtd = sorted(mods, key=lambda x: int(rgx.match(x).group(1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Given this input:

```
my_text = '''model_1_depth/depth_w/read/_79__cf__79
model_2_depth/depth_w/read/_73__cf__73
model_3_depth/depth_w/read/_67__cf__67
model_4_depth/depth_w/read/_61__cf__61
model_5_depth/depth_w/read/_55__cf__55
model_6_depth/depth_w/read/_49__cf__49
model_7_depth/depth_w/read/_43__cf__43
model_8_depth/depth_w/read/_37__cf__37
model_9_depth/depth_w/read/_31__cf__31
model_10_depth/depth_w/read/_25__cf__25
model_11_depth/depth_w/read/_19__cf__19
model_12_depth/depth_w/read/_13__cf__13
model_13_depth/depth_w/read/_7__cf__7
model_13_point/weights/read/_4__cf__4
model_12_point/weights/read/_10__cf__10
model_11_point/weights/read/_16__cf__16
model_10_point/weights/read/_22__cf__22
model_9_point/weights/read/_28__cf__28
model_8_point/weights/read/_34__cf__34
model_7_point/weights/read/_40__cf__40
model_6_point/weights/read/_46__cf__46
model_5_point/weights/read/_52__cf__52
model_4_point/weights/read/_58__cf__58
model_3_point/weights/read/_64__cf__64
model_2_point/weights/read/_70__cf__70
model_1_point/weights/read/_76__cf__76
model_0/weights/read/_82__cf__82'''
```

You can do the following:

```
my_text = my_text.split('\n')

b = sorted(my_text, key=lambda x: int(x.split('/')[0].split('_')[1]))
my_text_out = '\n'.join(b)
print(my_text_out)
```

Which results in this:

```
model_0/weights/read/_82__cf__82
model_1_depth/depth_w/read/_79__cf__79
model_1_point/weights/read/_76__cf__76
model_2_depth/depth_w/read/_73__cf__73
model_2_point/weights/read/_70__cf__70
model_3_depth/depth_w/read/_67__cf__67
model_3_point/weights/read/_64__cf__64
model_4_depth/depth_w/read/_61__cf__61
model_4_point/weights/read/_58__cf__58
model_5_depth/depth_w/read/_55__cf__55
model_5_point/weights/read/_52__cf__52
model_6_depth/depth_w/read/_49__cf__49
model_6_point/weights/read/_46__cf__46
model_7_depth/depth_w/read/_43__cf__43
model_7_point/weights/read/_40__cf__40
model_8_depth/depth_w/read/_37__cf__37
model_8_point/weights/read/_34__cf__34
model_9_depth/depth_w/read/_31__cf__31
model_9_point/weights/read/_28__cf__28
model_10_depth/depth_w/read/_25__cf__25
model_10_point/weights/read/_22__cf__22
model_11_depth/depth_w/read/_19__cf__19
model_11_point/weights/read/_16__cf__16
model_12_depth/depth_w/read/_13__cf__13
model_12_point/weights/read/_10__cf__10
model_13_depth/depth_w/read/_7__cf__7
model_13_point/weights/read/_4__cf__4
```

But as I said in the comments, a regex solution feels more appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works too! The regex solution I believe is this: `sorted(dictionary, key=lambda key: int(re.sub("_", "", re.sub(r'[^\w]', '', key[6:8]))))`, which I modified slightly from someone else who posted earlier on by adding an int in front of it (don't know where his answer went). Thank you all for the quick response.